# How to change customized text color of selected tab by programmatic in android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, textview, android-tabs

I am using tab widget for my application. My code is here main.xml http://pastie.org/8491814 and tab_layout.xml http://pastie.org/8491816. In this main.xml I created separate linear layout for my tab text.I can able to change my tab image while selecting tab using by selector.  Now i want to change my text view color while selecting tab. My TabActivity http://pastie.org/8491823. How can i chnage my text view color of tab? Can any body help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I can able to change my text while selecting tab using by selector" - Where you have done this?

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
 for (int i = 0;i<mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                 mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab);
                 TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
                 tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
             }
             TextView t = (TextView) mTabHost.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(android.R.id.title); //for Selected Tab
             t.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

You can change the color of tab text and background of tab

Comment: This is for default text view. But I am creating customized text view. Please see my mian.xml file.

Comment: but you say that you want to change the color of tab textview.